# Which integers can be written in form $\frac {(x+y+z)^2}{xyz}$,where $ x,y,z $ are positive integers?

Tags: number-theory

Question:Which integers can be written in form $\frac {(x+y+z)^2}{xyz}$,where $x,y,z$ are positive integers?

I suppose $ f(x,y,z)=\frac {(x+y+z)^2}{xyz}=n$

$nxyz=(x+y+z)^2$

$nxyz=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx$

$nxyz=(x+y)^2+2(yz+zx)+z^2$

After that i got stuck, I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: See [Toronto Mathematics Competition](https://books.google.at/books?id=YNn7CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=which+integers+can+be+written+in+the+form+(x%2By%2Bz)%5E2/xyz&source=bl&ots=8PQM8N8-xE&sig=ACfU3U0iqPdvMV27s9IMdzFLLTcBmpkncQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj76s3n66jpAhVSwMQBHZNkDoMQ6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=which%20integers%20can%20be%20written%20in%20the%20form%20(x%2By%2Bz)%5E2%2Fxyz&f=false).

Comment: The answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627475/how-many-integers-less-than-1000-can-be-expressed-in-the-form-fracx-y?rq=1) is also helpful.

Comment: $\dfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{xyz}=n \implies \Bigl(2 (x + y + z) - n y z\Bigr)^2 + \Bigl(2 (y + z)\Bigr)^2 = \Bigl(n y z - 2 (y + z)\Bigr)^2$

Comment: look here please: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1832412p12273114

Comment: I gave a very careful answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930438/equation-with-vieta-jumping-xyz2-nxyz/1930796#1930796