# How prove this inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b(a^2-ab+b^2)}\ge\frac{9}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality

let $a,b,c>0$, show that
$$\dfrac{a^2}{b(a^2-ab+b^2)}+\dfrac{b^2}{c(b^2-bc+c^2)}+\dfrac{c^2}{a(c^2-ca+a^2)}\ge\dfrac{9}{a+b+c}$$

My try: since this inequality is  homogeneous ,without loss of generality, we assume that
$$a+b+c=3$$
then

$$\Longleftrightarrow  \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{b(a^2-ab+b^2)}\ge 3$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2(a+b)}{b(a^3+b^3)}\ge 3$$

then I can't,Thank you

Comment: I do not think you can assume that their sum is three, since that then limits the range of each of them to 0->3.

Comment: By the way, there's no problem to assume $a+b+c = 3$ at all. Homogenity argument allows one to assume $a+b+c = C$ for any positive C.

Comment: Setting $a=\frac1x$, and similarly $y,z$, the inequality becomes $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^3(x+y)}{x^3+y^3}\geq\frac{9xyz}{xy+yz+zx}.$$ This makes the LHS look nicer, but I didn't find a way out from here yet. Note that this is also equivalent to $$2(x+y+z)\geq\frac{9xyz}{xy+yz+zx}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^3(x+y)}{x^3+y^3}.$$ So finding an appropriate upperbound (if that's easier) is enough.

Comment: This problem is routinely solvable using Lagrange multipliers.

Answer (score 5):

[image]       [image]              [image]

**Proof without words** ( partial answer / *informal* proof ) .

A formal proof has been given in another answer by another author.

- Picture on the left: geometry of the conditions $a,b,c > 0$ and $a+b+c=3$ .
- Picture in the middle: *outside* ($< 0$ : olive green) and *inside* ($\ge 0$ : white) of the function:
  $$f(a,b,c) = \sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b(a^2-ab+b^2)} - \frac{9}{a+b+c}$$
  as seen in the plane of the red triangle in the picture on the left.
  Since there are no green spots inside the triangle, the function is expected to be $\ge 0$ there.
- Picture on the right: contour lines of $f(a,b,c)$ inside the triangle at levels $N = 1/2^k \;; \; k=0,\cdots,7$ . Contours are darker at lower level values.
  The minimum is expected to be $f(1,1,1)=0$ , which is at the center of the triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Here is brutal force method which is ugly but solid.

the inequality equals:

$ \iff b^3c^6-ab^2c^6+a^2bc^6+a^3c^6-8ab^3c^5+8a^2b^2c^5-8a^3bc^5+8ab^4c^4+a^2b^3c^4-a^3b^2c^4+8a^4bc^4+b^6c^3-8ab^5c^3-a^2b^4c^3-6a^3b^3c^3+a^4b^2c^3-8a^5bc^3+a^6c^3+ab^6c^2+8a^2b^5c^2+a^3b^4c^2-a^4b^3c^2+8a^5b^2c^2-a^6bc^2-a^2b^6c-8a^3b^5c+8a^4b^4c-8a^5b^3c+a^6b^2c+a^3b^6+a^6b^3 \ge 0$

let $a=Min${$a,b,c$},$b=a+u,c=a+v,u \ge 0,v\ge0$ ,then we have:

$\iff 2(v^2-uv+u^2)a^7+2(2v^3-4uv^2+5u^2v+2u^3)a^6+6(v^4-3uv^3+2u^2v^2+3u^3v+u^4)a^5+(4v^5-9uv^4-8u^2v^3+26u^3v^2+19u^4v+4u^5)a^4+2(v^6-2uv^5+u^3v^3+13u^4v^2+4u^5v+u^6)a^3+2uv(v^5-2uv^4+4u^2v^3+3u^3v^2+4u^4v+2u^5)a^2+2u^2v^2(v^4-uv^3+4u^2v^2-u^3v+2u^4)a+u^3v^3(v^3+u^3) \ge 0$

the last one is true, and it is trivial when $u=v=0$, the "=" will hold.$\implies a=b=c$, the LHS=RHS.

QED.

Comment: I think this proof is incomplete, as you cannot always assume $a\leq b \leq c$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy, he only assumes $a$ is the minimum - doesn't seem to assume $u \ge v$ or vice versa.

Comment: @Sanchez Got it, thank you